# Two spans next to each other in a div, center one of them

Tags: css

I want to put two spans next to each other in a div and center **one** of the spans. However, I if I text-align:center the outer div then (of course) it is the combination of the two spans that will be centered. What is proper CSS code for the classes below? Thanks!

```
<div class="div_with_spans">
<span class="span_centered">Centered text</span><span class="span_next">More teext</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the CSS you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make the centered span a block element and center the text inside it:

```css
.span_centered {display:block; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="div_with_spans">
  <span class="span_centered">Centered text</span>
  <span class="span_next">More teext</span>
</div>
```

**Update**

to center the text but have the more text to the right of the centered text, you would need to  change the structure of your html and take the the more text out of the flow of the page

```css
.div_with_spans {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.span_centered {
  position: relative;
}

.span_next {
  margin-left:0.75em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_with_spans">
  <span class="span_centered">
    Centered text
    <span class="span_next">More teext</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Now "More text" ends up on a new line (also when removing line-break between the two spans).

Comment: What do you want to happen to the more text span?

Comment: The only way to do that with pure css is to change your html structure - you would need to put the next text inside the centered text span - See edit to answer

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I wanted, thanks Pete!